# The discrete random variable only takes the values $0$, $1$ and $2$. Moreover you know that $P(X=0)=P(X=2)$ and $P(X=1)=0.57$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

The discrete random variable only takes the values $0$, $1$ and $2$. Moreover you know that $P(X=0)=P(X=2)$ and $P(X=1)=0.57$.

Determine the value of $Var(X)$. Round your answer to two decimal numbers.

**MY WORKING**

I know that $Var(X)=E(X^{2})-E(X)^{2}$; Where:

$E(X)=0P(X=0)+1P(X=1)+2P(X=2)=0.57+2P(X=2)$

$E(X^{2})=0^{2}P(X=0)+1^{2}P(X=1)+2^{2}P(X=2)=0.57+4P(X=2)$

Now I don't know how to go further since I don't know the value of $P(X=2)$. Can anyone help me. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: $P(X = 0) + P(X = 2) = 1 - 0.57$

Comment: Also you have a typo in $E(X^2)$. $P(X=4)$ should be $P(X=2)$.

Comment: Still It's not clear to me how do I find value of $P(X=2)$ from $P(X=0)+P(X=2)=0.43$ .

Comment: They are equal as per question, right?

Comment: System of equations. Two unknowns: $P(X = 0)$ and $P(X = 2)$. Two equations: @MathLover 's two comments.

Comment: Yes I got the point. Thanks for your addition sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1$

$P(X=0)=P(X=2)$ and $P(X=1)=0.57$

$2\cdot P(X=2)+0.57=1\Rightarrow2\cdot P( X=2)=0.43$

$\Rightarrow P(X=2)=0.215$